Pseudo potential generation for XPS calculation
I want to compute the XPS spectrum for an iron oxide using pseudo potentials, and I would need some guidance in how to generate the necessary pseudo potentials. I am using a great software called APE where I can specify (among others) the core radii, the pseudo potential generation scheme (Troullier-Martins), core corrections if needed, and most importantly, the electronic configuration. In order to generate a pseudo potential for the core ionized O ion, I simply (naively?) take the same input file that I use to obtain the pseudo potential for the neutral O and change the electronic configuration to one where the 1s orbital has only 1 electron.
Is it as simple as this? Can anyone give me some guidance on what is the right procedure? Are there any other considerations? Any hints, insights, suggested papers would be very welcome!

Yes, broadly speaking this is the correct procedure. I will of course, reiterate the usual warnings about custom pseudopotentials -- they are very easily to make badly if you don't know what you are doing, so be very careful.
The usual caveat given is to test to make sure you get sensible results, and usually the Birch-Murnaghan Equation of States plots are considered a good test. Unfortunately for "excited state pseudopotentials" these are not useful (the bulk excited state will never exist).
I would consider that the first step is to make sure you have a good unexcited pseudopotential (test that robustly), and then adapt that as you suggest by generating in an excited state configuration. You should also test in that configuration to demonstrate that you see a good convergence of your pseudo and all-electron wavefunctions at the cut-off radius (so they match, and their gradients match).
For an in-depth discussion of this, I would consider having a look at the PhD thesis of Chris Pickard, which if memory serves, contains a detailed description of excited state pseudopotentials in the context of core-loss EELS. It should be findable with a google search!
Hope that helps,
Rob

Thank you very much, Rob, for the insightful comment!
Luckily, we can be sure that the unexcited pseudo potential is good. The comparison of the pseudo and all-atom wave function and energies for the excited state is a good idea! I just found Chris Pickard's thesis, I'll check it out!
